# Custom Hook Returning Empty Array From Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm a newly self-taught coder. Hopefully I'm expressing my situation adequately.

I'm trying to retrieve some data from Cloud Firestore. I've made a custom hook that should useState and setDocuments to the be the retrieved "guide". The query uses useParams to get the id to match to the specific guide I'm trying to get. I think the issue is in the querySnapshot. setDocuments doesn't seem to be working. When I console log "documents" it's an empty array.

Any leads?

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config"
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const useGuide = (c) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const { id } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {

    const ref = collection(db, c)
    const q = query(ref, where("id", "==", `${id}`))

    getDocs(q).then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        setDocuments(doc.data()) 
      });
    });
  }, [])

  console.log(documents)

  return { documents }
}
```

Here is where I try to use the hook useGuide to set the state which would be passed to a component.

```
import SingleGuide from '../../components/SingleGuide/SingleGuide'
import { useGuide } from '../../hooks/useGuide'

function Guide() {
    const { documents: guides } = useGuide('guides')
    console.log(guides)
                
  return (
      <div>
          {guides && <SingleGuide guide={guides}/>}
      </div>
  )
}

export default Guide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code including setting an array of docs equal to a single doc in the query results. Try something like the following.

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useGuide = (c) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // create array to hold all the individual docs
    const docs = [];
    const ref = collection(db, c);
    const q = query(ref, where("id", "==", `${id}`));

    getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push(doc.data());
      });

      setDocuments(docs);
    });
  }, [c]); // could consider passing `id` to the hook instead of useParams and adding that as a dependency to update data automatically

  console.log(documents);

  return { documents };
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns an empty array. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @jakeycodez If you log out `docs` before setDocuments is executed, does it have data? If you add `catch` to the query, does it log an error? How are you actually using this hook elsewhere? Does `useParams` id resolve effectively as well?

Comment: All great questions. I edited my question to include where the hook is being used. useParams does log the correct id I need. If I log docs before setDocuments it seems to not even log anything, meaning it's not getting that far in the code? I'm getting closer. Again thank you so much, all great questions to consider.

Comment: So first step, try adding `.catch(err => console.log(err))` to the `getDocs(q)`. Can you try logging something like `console.log(querySnapshot.docs.length)` inside the `.then()`?

Comment: Hey! So adding the .catch returns no errors - but I think something there worked. I am now able to log the documents and see the data I needed. Really appreciate all your help Alexander!